# Error while running configure during RVM install 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

While running 'rvm install 1.9.3' I get the following error:

> Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/jordan/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/jordan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
>   There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

This is the output of configure.log:

```
[2012-05-07 19:07:43]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml  --with-opt-dir=/Users/jordan/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++-4.2 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 needs -traditional... no
checking whether the linker is GNU ld... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -E accepts -o... yes
checking for real target cpu... x86_64
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for objdump... no
checking for gobjdump... no
checking for objcopy... no
checking for gobjcopy... no
checking for nm... nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p...  -d
use 'mkdir -p' as MKDIR_P
checking for dot... no
checking for doxygen... no
checking for pkg-config... pkg-config
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for cd using physical directory... cd -P
checking whether -Wno-unused-parameter is accepted... yes
checking whether -Wno-parentheses is accepted... yes
checking whether -Wno-long-long is accepted... yes
checking whether -Wno-missing-field-initializers is accepted... yes
checking whether -Werror=pointer-arith is accepted... yes
checking whether -Werror=write-strings is accepted... yes
checking whether -Werror=declaration-after-statement is accepted... yes
checking whether -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 is accepted... yes
checking whether -Werror=implicit-function-declaration is accepted... yes
checking whether -Wextra is accepted... yes
checking whether -ggdb is accepted... yes
checking whether -fvisibility=hidden is accepted... yes
checking whether -Wl,-unexported_symbol,_Init_* is accepted... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether char is unsigned... no
checking for inline... inline
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for long long... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking char bit... 8
checking size of int... 4
checking size of short... 2
checking size of long... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of __int64... 0
checking size of off_t... 8
checking size of void*... 8
checking size of float... 4
checking size of double... 8
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for printf prefix for long long... ll
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for convertible type of pid_t... INT
checking for uid_t... yes
checking for convertible type of uid_t... UINT
checking for gid_t... yes
checking for convertible type of gid_t... UINT
checking for time_t... yes
checking for convertible type of time_t... LONG
checking for dev_t... yes
checking for convertible type of dev_t... INT
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for convertible type of mode_t... UINT
checking for rlim_t... yes
checking for convertible type of rlim_t... ULL
checking for prototypes... yes
checking token paste string... ansi
checking stringization... #expr
checking string literal concatenation... yes
checking for variable length prototypes and stdarg.h... yes
checking for variable length macro... yes
checking for noreturn function attribute... __attribute__ ((noreturn)) x
checking for deprecated function attribute... __attribute__ ((deprecated)) x
checking for noinline function attribute... __attribute__ ((noinline)) x
checking for stdcall function attribute... x
checking for cdecl function attribute... x
checking for fastcall function attribute... x
checking for function alias... no
checking for atomic builtins... yes
checking for exported function attribute... __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
checking whether sys_nerr is declared... yes
checking whether Mac OS X 10.5 or later... yes
checking for broken crypt with 8bit chars... no
checking for crypt in -lcrypt... (cached) no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for socketpair in -lsocket... no
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... no
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/syscall.h usability... yes
checking sys/syscall.h presence... yes
checking for sys/syscall.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking sys/fcntl.h usability... yes
checking sys/fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/fcntl.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking syscall.h usability... no
checking syscall.h presence... no
checking for syscall.h... no
checking pwd.h usability... yes
checking pwd.h presence... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking grp.h usability... yes
checking grp.h presence... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking a.out.h usability... no
checking a.out.h presence... no
checking for a.out.h... no
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking direct.h usability... no
checking direct.h presence... no
checking for direct.h... no
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking sys/mkdev.h usability... no
checking sys/mkdev.h presence... no
checking for sys/mkdev.h... no
checking sys/utime.h usability... no
checking sys/utime.h presence... no
checking for sys/utime.h... no
checking xti.h usability... no
checking xti.h presence... no
checking for xti.h... no
checking netinet/in_systm.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in_systm.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in_systm.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking ieeefp.h usability... no
checking ieeefp.h presence... no
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking for ucontext.h... (cached) no
checking intrinsics.h usability... no
checking intrinsics.h presence... no
checking for intrinsics.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking sys/sendfile.h usability... no
checking sys/sendfile.h presence... no
checking for sys/sendfile.h... no
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for net/socket.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
checking process.h usability... no
checking process.h presence... no
checking for process.h... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking size of size_t... 8
checking size of ptrdiff_t... 8
checking for printf prefix for size_t... z
checking for printf prefix for ptrdiff_t... t
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blocks... yes
checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes
checking size of struct stat.st_size... SIZEOF_LONG
checking size of struct stat.st_blocks... SIZEOF_LONG
checking for struct stat.st_atim... no
checking for struct stat.st_atimespec... yes
checking for struct stat.st_atimensec... no
checking for struct stat.st_mtim... no
checking for struct stat.st_mtimespec... yes
checking for struct stat.st_mtimensec... no
checking for struct stat.st_ctim... no
checking for struct stat.st_ctimespec... yes
checking for struct stat.st_ctimensec... no
checking for struct timespec... yes
checking for struct timezone... yes
checking for clockid_t... no
checking for fd_mask... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking size of int8_t... 1
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking size of uint8_t... 1
checking for int16_t... yes
checking size of int16_t... 2
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking size of uint16_t... 2
checking for int32_t... yes
checking size of int32_t... 4
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking size of uint32_t... 4
checking for int64_t... yes
checking size of int64_t... 8
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking size of uint64_t... 8
checking for int128_t... no
checking for uint128_t... no
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking size of intptr_t... 8
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking size of uintptr_t... 8
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking size of ssize_t... 8
checking for stack end address... no
checking for gc_mark and gc_children stack frame approximate size(word)... 20
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking type of array argument to getgroups... (cached) gid_t
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for dynamic size alloca... ok
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for broken erfc of glibc-2.3.6 on IA64... no
checking for dup2... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for crypt... yes
checking for flock... yes
checking for isnan... yes
checking for finite... yes
checking for isinf... yes
checking for hypot... yes
checking for acosh... yes
checking for erf... yes
checking for tgamma... yes
checking for lgamma_r... yes
checking for cbrt... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for strlcat... yes
checking for ffs... yes
checking for setproctitle... no
checking for signbit... yes
checking for fmod... yes
checking for killpg... yes
checking for wait4... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for spawnv... no
checking for syscall... yes
checking for __syscall... yes
checking for chroot... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for eaccess... no
checking for truncate... yes
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for ftello... yes
checking for chsize... no
checking for times... yes
checking for utimes... yes
checking for utimensat... no
checking for fcntl... yes
checking for lockf... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for truncate64... no
checking for ftruncate64... no
checking for ftello64... no
checking for fseeko... yes
checking for fseeko64... no
checking for link... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for readdir_r... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for fdatasync... (cached) no
checking for fchown... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... no
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for setruid... yes
checking for seteuid... yes
checking for setreuid... yes
checking for setresuid... no
checking for socketpair... yes
checking for setrgid... yes
checking for setegid... yes
checking for setregid... yes
checking for setresgid... no
checking for issetugid... yes
checking for pause... yes
checking for lchown... yes
checking for lchmod... yes
checking for getpgrp... yes
checking for setpgrp... yes
checking for getpgid... yes
checking for setpgid... yes
checking for initgroups... yes
checking for getgroups... yes
checking for setgroups... yes
checking for getpriority... yes
checking for getrlimit... yes
checking for setrlimit... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for close... yes
checking for getgrnam_r... yes
checking for dlopen... yes
checking for sigprocmask... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigsetjmp... yes
checking for _setjmp... yes
checking for _longjmp... yes
checking for setsid... yes
checking for telldir... yes
checking for seekdir... yes
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for cosh... yes
checking for sinh... yes
checking for tanh... yes
checking for log2... yes
checking for round... yes
checking for setuid... yes
checking for setgid... yes
checking for daemon... (cached) no
checking for select_large_fdset... no
checking for setenv... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for mktime... yes
checking for timegm... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for clock_gettime... no
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for poll... yes
checking for ppoll... no
checking for pread... yes
checking for sendfile... yes
checking for shutdown... yes
checking for sigaltstack... yes
checking for dl_iterate_phdr... no
checking for unsetenv returns a value... yes
checking for __builtin_setjmp... no
checking for setjmp type... _setjmp
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff... yes
checking for external int daylight... yes
checking for external timezone... long
checking for external altzone... no
checking for timezone... yes
checking whether timezone requires zero arguments... yes
checking for negative time_t for gmtime(3)... yes
checking for localtime(3) overflow correctly... yes
checking whether right shift preserve sign bit... yes
checking read count field in FILE structures... _r
checking read buffer ptr field in FILE structures... _p
checking size of struct stat.st_ino... SIZEOF_LONG
checking whether _SC_CLK_TCK is supported... yes
checking stack growing direction on x86_64... -1
checking for pthread_kill in -lthr... no
checking for pthread_kill in -lpthread... yes
checking for pthread_np.h... no
checking for sched_yield... yes
checking for pthread_attr_setinheritsched... yes
checking for pthread_getattr_np... no
checking for pthread_attr_get_np... no
checking for pthread_attr_getstack... yes
checking for pthread_get_stackaddr_np... yes
checking for pthread_get_stacksize_np... yes
checking for thr_stksegment... no
checking for pthread_stackseg_np... no
checking for pthread_getthrds_np... no
checking for pthread_condattr_setclock... no
checking for pthread_sigmask... yes
checking if fork works with pthread... yes
checking for backtrace... yes
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking whether ELF binaries are produced... no
checking whether OS depend dynamic link works... yes
checking for strip... strip
checking for prefix of external symbols... _
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for if make is GNU make... yes
checking for nroff... /usr/bin/nroff
.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/ruby/config.h updated
ruby library version = 1.9.1
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating ruby-1.9.pc
Unknown keyword 'URL' in './ruby.tmp.pc'
```

I'm running lion, and I've got the latest version of XCode, and have downloaded command line tools.  I've seen many people have issues with gcc but that doesn't seem to be the issue in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Has it correctly created the Makefile?  It doesn't actually say error in this log output.

Comment: Ah, oops, overlooked the first part of the post ;)

Comment: have you installed Xcode commandline tools? or try with osx-gcc-installer.

Comment: I've downloaded the osx-gcc-installer, and tried running 'CC=gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3' but got the same result. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I got the same message but it did not give any error. The Makefile got generated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have old version of pkg-config in you path.
run `pkg-config --version` , it should be 0.25 with Xcode 4.3.2.
And it should be in `/usr/local/bin`. If you have an old version in `/usr/bin` ,you can just remove it and everything will be cool.

Comment: Yep, my pkg-config version was 0.15.  Thanks for the help!